# 'showNotification' of undefined for push notifications

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

I am trying to push my website notifications from browser to android and pc, for that I tried [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications#understanding_push_notifications_on_the_web).

I followed the documentation and put the following code -

```
Notification.requestPermission(function(status) {
    console.log('Notification permission status:', status);
});

function displayNotification() {
  if (Notification.permission == 'granted') {
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(function(reg) {
      console.log("Reg -"+reg);
      reg.showNotification('Hello world!');
    });
  }
  else{
    console.log(Notification.permission);
  }
}
```

Permission is `granted` but I am getting error with `reg` because it is getting `undefined`.

here is screenshot of my console -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the tab "Application" -> "Service Workers" on the Chrome debug panel.
I think you didn't connect a service worker in your app.
For Notification logic you need to create any service worker and enable it.

For example add the following code in your root js-file:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');
}
```

and create a file `sw.js` with the following content:

```
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    console.log('Installed');
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    console.log('Activated');
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    console.log('Fetch request');
});
```

P.S. And your `console.log("Reg -"+reg);` is before the `reg` init, so it is `undefined` :)